# Dom grid, fluid inside of fixed and more

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, less

I've wrestled with this for a long time, and ended up resorting to jQuery hacks. I'd really like to know if there is a way to implement this with CSS or LESS (using javascript mixins).

It's essentially a page with assorted fixed and fluid elements.

http://cl.ly/IagL

Any ideas on best practice?

Comment: May be I could not understand you well. However, did you checked a css framework like http://foundation.zurb.com/ to get what do want?!

Comment: why is that "?!" and yes I have, but all of the css frameworks I have seen are a mix width situation 960, 980, etc. This is supposed to fill the browser width and height

Comment: I think you can do it with CSS or LESS, and maybe with some jquery

Comment: Correct me please, How could we get fluid thing inside a fixed thing?!!

Comment: stop being overly aggressive with the exclamations...

Comment: You'll need Jquery to calculate fluid width between two fixed width divs.

Comment: I know thats not true, http://css-tricks.com/examples/LayoutPacks/FixedFluidFixed/ but I don't know the way to achieve the overall system.

Comment: the fluid height is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I see a problem if you want the height of left and right column to be equal with the height of the middle column. If you make the height as a fix height than you can do it, otherwise you need to use jquery.

But if you want to achieve the fluid width, I suggest you to use twitter bootstrap. Their framework support the use of LESS as well http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: this actually turns out to be a limitation with CSS

Answer (score 0):

The middle height is technically impossible with CSS and is a known issue. http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/telepathy/sometimes-css-cant-do-it-all

I guess I will have to resort to jQuery